# Trying to get the most occuring modal verb in a sentence

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have this code. The idea is to get the most occurring modal verb from a string. For example, if 'can' appears twice, and more than the rest, the function should return 'can', or return 'none' if no modal verb present.

```
def check_modals(s):
    modals = ['can', 'could', 'may', 'might', 'must', 'will', "should", "would"]
    from collections import Counter
    Counter([modal for modals, modal in s])
    counts = Counter(modals)
    c = counts.most_common(1)

    return{c}
```

Still a python newbie. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you instantiate your `Counter`, I would use a list comprehension to filter only including words that are present in the `modals` list. Other than that, you had the right idea.

```
def check_modals(s):
        modals = ['can', 'could', 'may', 'might', 'must', 'will', 'should', 'would']
        from collections import Counter
        counts = Counter([word for word in s if word in modals])
        if counts:
            return counts.most_common(1)[0][0]
        else:
            return ''

>>> s = 'This is a test sentence that may or may not have verbs'
>>> check_modals(s.split())
'may'
```

Comment: hi! thanks for your response. How can i make it return just 'may' as a word or string.

Comment: @user3078335 See my edit, you can just index `[0]` to get the first item in `most_common`, then `[0]` again to get the first element of that tuple.

Comment: Thanks alot! one more thing, what does the '.split' do?

Comment: @user3078335 [`split`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) is method of the `str` class that parses a string into a list of strings based on the delimiter specified. Since I did not specify a delimiter, it split on whitespace, and made a list of words.

Comment: I tried including this code at the end
 "c = counts.most_common(1)[0][0]
    return{c}  "
But i keep getting this error "IndexError: list index out of range"

Comment: Since I am checking multiple sentences, not all of them may have modal verbs, is that the reason this error arises?

Comment: @user3078335 Correct, I hadn't handled the case where the sentence had none of those words. See my edit, this is handled now.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than filtering the words, filter the counts:

```
from collections import Counter
def check_modals(s):
    counts = Counter(s)
    modals = ['can', 'could', 'may', 'might', 'must', 'will', "should", "would"]
    for key in counts.keys():
        if key not in modals:
            del counts[key]
    c = counts.most_common(1)
    return c[0][0]

print check_modals('can can'.split(' '))
```

Prints:

```
can
```

Answer (score 0):

Am I cheating?

```
def check_modals(s, modals={'can':0, 'could':0, 'may':0, 'might':0,
                            'must':0, 'will':0, "should":0, "would":0}):
    for w in s.split():
        if w in modals: modals[w]+=1
    # EDIT I will return both the most frequent and also the count number
    k, v = max(modals.iteritems(), key=lambda item:item[1])
    return (k, v) if v > 0 else (None, None)
```

from the interpreter

```
>>> s = '''I have this code. The idea is to get the most occurring modal verb from a string. For example, if 'can' appears twice, and more than the rest, the function should return 'can', and 'none' if no modal verb present.'''
>>> check_modal(s)
('should', 1)
>>>
```